# XSS preventing for parameters passed to JS code file

Tags: javascript, java, scala, security, xss

I have the following flow: A URL with query parameters, that runs some logic on the server side, and then generates using a template engine a stub HTML page with

- A javascript file included, that does the main logic.
- `<script>` tag that includes a JS object, that has parameters to this JS code, partially taken from the query parameters before.

Now I want to sanitize the parameters I receive, to prevent XSS injection. The issue, that one of the parameters there is a token, so I don't want to be too strict on the validations (simply not allowing all possible XSS characters sounds too strict), yet most of the libraries I've found dealing with pure HTML, and not a JS code (within `<script>` tag). I also feeling a bit uneasy, when I read all the regex solution, because I'm used to trust open source **libraries** when dealing with security (that have unit tests and not a bunch of regex).

Any advice on libraries & possible approach? We run in JVM environment.

Comment: I think you could html encode your query string parameter, then you can display them safely into your html response page. In java you can use org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

Comment: So you are passing the URL parameters as values of a JS obejct's properties, is that correct?

Comment: @mjsarfatti That's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest, simplest, and therefore more secure approach is to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to represent the dynamic, user supplied values.

This way you only need to worry about HTML encoding, none of the complex hex entity encoding (`\x00`) that [OWASP recommend](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values).

For example, you could have:

```
<body data-token="@param.token" />
```

Where `@param.token` will output an HTML encoded version of the query string parameter. e.g. `page?token=xyz"` would output

```
<body data-token="xyz&quot;" />
```

This will mitigate your XSS vulnerability concern.

Then you can use something like [JQuery to easy retrieve the data attribute values in your JavaScript](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var token = $("body").data("token");
```

Simple and secure.

Comment: OP, if you follow the above, be aware of how `token` is then used. It's not magically secure for all client-side JavaScript uses. If it ends up in say `$("foo").html(token)`, or any of the other innumerable unsafe methods, you will then be vulnerable to a DOM-based XSS issue instead of your original reflected XSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Imagining you want to assign your parameter as a string, as such:

```
{
  ...
  x: '[PARAMETER]'
}
```

You want to make sure that *[PARAMETER]* does not break out of the quoted string.

In this case what you need to escape is the `'` character and the closing `</script>`tag. Note: take into consideration "escape-the-escape" attacks, where the attacker sends the string `\'`, which is escaped as `\\'`, which turns back to `'` (and you are back from where you started).

It's generally simply safer, as OWASP notes, to

> escape all characters less than 256 with the \xHH format

I invite you to read the OWASP page on XSS attacks, and in particular https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values

Comment: This approach unfortunately is vulnerable to an attacker passing `</script>` to break out of the script tag. The attacker can then follow up their string with another `<script>` and then insert their payload. The OWASP article you mentioned even states this: `DO NOT use any escaping shortcuts like \" ` and recommends ` \xHH` for all non-alphanumeric characters.